# "I don't have time for this" preposition

Tags: предлоги

So I had to translate this sentence and I thought it'd be just `У меня нет времени за это`, but I have a lot of trouble when using certain prepositions. In this case for example, I would have no idea whether to use `за` or `для`, so my first question is which one is correct.

I know that `для` is supposed to mean more like "for the purpose of" but I couldn't tell in this particular sentence, are they interchangeable?

My second question is, Google Translate uses the preposition `на` in the sentence I have time for this, and I don't understand why. I only know this preposition to be used as in/on. And "for" only when used with time to mean "for the duration of" a certain amount of time. So am I missing a meaning here as well?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both "на это" and "для этого" would be appropriate here, although you would encounter the first one more often.

Consider the phrase 'to spend time **on** something'. The Russian phrase actually means "У меня нет времени *[, чтобы потратить его]* на это" ('I don't have time [to spend it] on that').

Comment: And why за with the meaning of "for" wouldn't be acceptable instead of для?

Comment: "За" would mean "for" as in "[in exchange] for", not as "for [the sake of]", and is not suitable in this case.